# How change the format of Xaxis (times) to an other format ? Python - Pandas - Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I tried to create a bar chart, but i have a problem with the X-axis format. In the graph I have year-month-day 00:00:00. But I would like just year-month, so I tried this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

ax = df_graph.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(12, 8), legend=False) 

plt.title('Groups Unavailability by Month')
plt.ylabel('Unavailability (hours)')
plt.xlabel('Date (Year-Month)')

hfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)

plt.xticks(rotation=0)
```

The three lines hftm, major_locator, major_formatter have no effects...

Thanks for your time !

Comment: My understanding is that pandas doesn't handle this kind of thing well. You can drop into base matplotlib and it will work.

Comment: Bar plots actually just plot the bars against `range(len(df))` and annotate the ticks with the corresponding labels.

Comment: @mechanical_meat Yeah, I had a doubt about it. But to manage the dataframe, columns it's more suitable, I think...